# Symfony - Cannot read property 'stripTime' Error

Tags: javascript, php, symfony

Im using ancarebeca/FullCalendarBundle and ive set enverything up correctly.

When i try to access the calendar layout i dont get events on the page, i only got them when i access /full-calendar/load in array !

This is the error i get :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'stripTime' of undefined
at v (fullcalendar.min.js:6)
at u (fullcalendar.min.js:6)
at t (fullcalendar.min.js:6)
at s (fullcalendar.min.js:6)
at fullcalendar.min.js:6
at Object.success (fullcalendar.min.js:6)
at j (jquery.min.js:2)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
at x (jquery.min.js:4)
at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:4)
```

This is my head layout :

```html
{% block stylesheets %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/fullcalendar/css/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.css') }}" />
{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('bundles/fullcalendar/js/fullcalendar/lib/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-confirmation/1.0.7/bootstrap-confirmation.js"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('bundles/fosjsrouting/js/router.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ path('fos_js_routing_js', { callback: 'fos.Router.setData' }) }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('bundles/fullcalendar/js/fullcalendar/lib/moment.min.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('bundles/fullcalendar/js/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('bundles/fullcalendar/js/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.default-settings.js') }}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

I dont know why i get this type of error, the bundle must work correctly

Thanks for helping

Comment: Verify if the fullcalendar version of jQuery is the 3.2.*. Mixing JQuery versions is rarely good.

Comment: Ive tried to put just the jquery file from fcalendar, nothing works
Also ive tried to put just jquery file from google and nothing works